Best Statistical Analysis Method for Short Panel Data
I am conducting a research project that examines the simultaneous and partial effects of several independent variables on a dependent variable using a short panel dataset with 175 observations over 2 time periods (T = 2).
Given the limitations of my dataset, I am particularly interested in statistical analysis methods that can effectively address unobserved heterogeneity and potential endogeneity issues. I have considered methods like multiple regression and panel data analysis but would appreciate insights on more robust alternatives or specific techniques that might be applicable to my context. What statistical methods would you recommend for analyzing short panel data?

What do you mean "effectively address unobserved heterogeneity and potential endogeneity issues"? If they are unobserved, then I'm not sure how you can address it, and if there are endogeneity issues, you should make clear what you mean by this being a problem.
